# Deauthorize Amazon EC2 Security Group rule from command line with API tools

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, port-forwarding

I know that `ec2-authorize {security group} -p {port #} ...` will authorize a new rule; my question is, how can I deauthorize a rule from commandline? I tried `ec2-deauthorize ...` with no success :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The corresponding command is [`ec2-revoke`](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonEC2/dg/2006-10-01/CLTRG-revoke.html). It takes the same arguments as `ec2-authorize`.